# Why I have to send params as an object in $http angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making CRUD and if I want to send some data to my backend (node.js) then I receive an error: 
`angular.js:10765 POST http://localhost:1234/shop/removeProduct/574bf938b16158b40f9c87bc 400 (Bad Request)`

script:

```
$scope.removeProduct = function (partnerId, productId) {
    $http.post("/campaign/removeProduct/" + partnerId, productId);
}
```

The solution is just simply pack this parameter (`productId`) in an object like this:

```
$scope.removeProduct = function (partnerId, productId) {
    $scope.productData = {productId: productId};
    $http.post("/campaign/removeProduct/" + partnerId, $scope.productData);
}
```

But why I have to do this like this? By the way, is this correct or should I do it in a different way?

---

@EDIT
One more thing, how should i refresh data after I added/removed any object?
Is this correct?

```
$scope.addPartner = function(data) {
$http({method: 'POST', url: addPartner, data})
.then(function(response) {
console.log(response);
});
$scope.loadPartnersData();
window.alert("Partner added!");
};

$scope.loadPartnersData = function () {
$http.get("/campaign/partner-list").then(function(result) {
$scope.partnerList = result.data.partnerList;
});
};
```

backend:

```
router.get('/partner-list', function (req, res) {
    Partner.find({}, function (err, partnerList) {
        if (err) throw err;

        res.json({ partnerList: partnerList });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why does your server code need id both in url and in payload? Can your backend use `DELETE` verb w/o payload to perform delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the url to be something like `/shop/removeProduct/34523543?productData=5325345`. If so then I would use the angular way of declaring `$http` request:

```
var url = '/shop/removeProduct/' + partnerId; /* How ever you declare this */
$scope.removeProduct = function() {
  $http({method: 'POST', url, params:{'productData': productId}})
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
};

$scope.removeProduct();
```

[Angular then takes care of the decoding of the parameters](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.0-beta.14/src/ng/http.js#L957)

Comment: Thank you. One more question. As i said before it's CRUD. In this case i want to remove some Product from Array in Partner Document. That's why i need to send `partnerId` and `productId`. At the moment I send `partnerId` in URL `'/shop/removeProduct/' + partnerId;` but is it correct? Maybe should I send `partnerId` and `productId` like this `$http({method: 'POST', url, params:{'partnerData': partnertId, 'productData': productId}})`

Comment: Well, I can't really tell you what your back-end is like. If it's CRUD it should be `$http({method: 'DELETE', url, params:{'partnerData': partnertId, 'productData': productId}})` or similar.

Comment: I can always change backend :)

Comment: Why it has to be `var url` in `$http({method: 'DELETE', url, params:{'productData': productId}})`. I tried `var urlRemoveProduct` and i receive an error: `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Comment: It does not have to be. I just use it normally like that. You can have it straight like: `$http({method: 'DELETE', '/campaign/removeProduct/', params:{'productData': productId}})`

Comment: Doesn't work, seriously. This is what i had to do: `var removePartner = '/campaign/removePartner'` and `$http({method: 'DELETE', url: removePartner, data})`

Comment: Yes this works, and it's weird. I thought `url` is only variable and may be called whatever. But it seems, has to be `key: value` which `key` is always called `url`

Comment: Ok that's a bit strange (dependant on your back-end) but I guess the main point is that you got it working :P

Comment: if you can, check EDIT from above

Comment: Please make a separate question about it or search for answers in Google or SO before you do that. There are plenty of answers for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the Content-Type header to `text/plain` if you send text:

```
$scope.removeProduct = function (partnerId, productId) {
   var config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" }};
   $http.post("/campaign/removeProduct/" + partnerId, productId, config);
}
```

This shoudl work, if your node route handler accepts `text/plain` content. (If you're using body-parser, make sure to add `app.use(bodyParser.text());`

In this particular case, it seems to make more sense to send a DELETE request to the resource uri like this:

```
$scope.removeProduct = function (partnerId, productId) {
   $http.delete("/campaign/partners/" + partnerId + '/products/' + productId);
}
```

And let your backend handle this like:

```
app.get('/campaign/partners/:partner/products/:product', function(req, res){
     myAwesomeDB.remove(req.params.product).then(/*...*/);
});
```